# Autoscaling web application

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, autoscaling

How to autoscale my web app so that it doesn't affect application performance.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-scaling can be an awesome solution. But like all solutions, it might not be perfect for *every* situation. If you have a predictable burst scenario like you do, having the extra instances up and running as soon as the burst is about to begin will improve performance. If the autoscale kicks in, you'll have to wait for the new instances to be up and running before they're available. This might take some time.

Please keep into account that horizontal scaling (or scaling in/out) is different than vertical scaling (or scaling down/up). If you do vertical scaling (where you increase or decrease the pricing tier of the application) might trigger a recycle of your application, while horizontal scaling 'only' adds instances of your application.

If I were in your shoes, I'd create a scheduled manual scale for the applications with a good amount of time before and after to facilitate ramp-up and clean-up. Warm-up scripts or a user that clicks through the application to make sure all resources are loaded are preferable.

For more information, see this [Auto-scaling guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling) article.

Comment: Thanks @Rick... nice explanation. So does it mean that during auto-scaling the system takes some time to spun up an instance. If this is the case then it might happen that by the time the instance is live the user has already felt the performance hit. Let me know if I am correct in my understanding

Comment: Yes, a user may have already felt the performance hit. This is, of course, for a large part dependent on the auto-scale settings you define. If you catch lots of traffic early by specifying good metrics values, your user might not get a performance hit.

Comment: When you know there is a burst of traffic coming in at a specific time "scheduled-autoscale" is definitely the way to go. You should also plan to do some scale testing ahead of time. Scale testing will help you predict how much load your app can take and how many instances you will need to survive the traffic spike.